# Google Sheet: Arrayforumla as sum_range argument in sumif throws error

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

[Screenshot with example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pl4yw.png)

I want to define the `sum_range` in an *sumif*-formula by using a range returned by an *arrayformula* but it gives me an error, not acknowledging it as a range. Using an *arrayformula* for the conditional range works however.

*This works:*

```
=sumif(
   ARRAYFORMULA({B1;C3;D5}),TRUE,
   A7:A9
)
```

*This doesn't:*

```
=sumif(
  ARRAYFORMULA({B1;C3;D5}),TRUE,
  ARRAYFORMULA({A1;B3;C5})
)
```

Am I doing something wrong here that I can't see or is it maybe just not possible? Maybe there's another smart way to do it..?

Answer (score 1):

Why not use

```
=sumif(B1:B3, "TRUE", A1:A3)
```

or even

```
=sumproduct(B1:B3, A1:A3)
```

instead ?

If you really need to use inline arrays this should work

```
=sumproduct({B1, B2, B3}, {A1, A2, A3})
```

---

#### Bool to Number Casting

`SUMPRODUCT` will automatically cast Booleans to Numbers, so `TRUE=1` and `FALSE=0`. If it doesn't, then the formula requires this to be a manual operation. You can leverage the `N()` formula to cast Booleans to Numbers manually.

### Reference

[N()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093357?hl=en)

[SUMPRODUCT()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094294?hl=en)

Comment: That actually seemed to work! So I guess sumproduct consider each TRUE and FALSE as 1 and 0 when it does its multplications?

Answer (score 0):

you don't need any `arrayformula` to use the `sumif` as the `sumif` accepts array ranges:

```
=sumif(B:B; true; A:A)
ranges:***        ***
```

the thing is that you may not have a multidimensional array in your `sum range` column, only a single array, however, in your `initial range` you can have any multidimensional array:

- `=sumif(B1:B3;true;{A1:A3})` - error
- `=sumif({B1:B3};true;A1:A3)` - works well
- `=sumif({B1:B3; B1:B3}; true; A1:A3)` - works well as well

Comment: The reason (I think) I need to use arrayformula is that the cells are not contiguous. Just putit that way in my example for the sake of simplicity..

Comment: I see. so I guess the real culprit here (for me anyway) is that `sum_range` won't accept any multidimensional arrays. I tested the sumproduct_suggestion from JPV and that actually worked.